# Having trouble uncollapsing a menu item in my sidebar in react

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a sidebar that has a few items in it, two of the items are collapsable items called "menu" and "pages". these items are supposed to collapse and uncollapse on click, but I can't get it to do that for some reason.

here is my code:

```
    import React from "react";
    import Flower from "../../Images/flower.png";
    import "./SideBar.css";
    import $ from "jquery";


    class SideBar extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    }

  render () {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="wrapper">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-header">
                <h3>`Bootstrap Sidebar`</h3>
                <strong>BS</strong>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-unstyled components">
                    <li className="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" className="dropdown-toggle">
                            <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                        <ul className="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                            About
                        </a>
                        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" className="dropdown-toggle">
                            <i className="fas fa-copy"></i>
                            Pages
                        </a>
                        <ul className="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="fas fa-image"></i>
                            Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="fas fa-question"></i>
                            FAQ
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul className="list-unstyled CTAs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" className="download">Download source</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" className="article">Back to article</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content">

                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div className="container-fluid">

                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-info">
                            <i className="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                            <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                        </button>
                        <button className="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i className="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                        </button>

                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li className="nav-item active">
                                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item">
                                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div className="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div className="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div className="line"></div>

                <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    );
  }
}
  
  export default SideBar;
```

and this is my css:

```
/* .sidebar {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
} */

/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

i,
span {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header h3,
#sidebar.active .CTAs {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-align: left;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

#sidebar.active ul li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#sidebar.active ul ul a {
    padding: 10px !important;
}

#sidebar.active .dropdown-toggle::after {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li a i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -80px !important;
    }
    .dropdown-toggle::after {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a span {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar ul ul a {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    #sidebar ul li a i {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for going through all these lines of code and helping my out.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had some missing CDNs from bootstrap and popper.